# ttk.OptionMenu() displaying check mark on all menus

Tags: python, tkinter, optionmenu

In this example, if a user selects any option in any of the drop downs, then clicks on another drop down, the previously selected item displayed a check mark beside it.  Even though that choice was picked in a different menu.

```
from Tkinter import *
from ttk import *

choices = ['1st Choice', '2nd Choice', '3rd Choice', '4th Choice']

root = Tk()

for each in range(10):
    OptionMenu(root, StringVar(), choices[0], *choices).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

This happens on both Python 2.7 and 3.5.

I've even moved the `choices` list into the loop so it generates on each iteration and the problem still occurs. I'm assuming since the elements of the list are the same objects tkinter isn't differentiating between which OptionMenu they are in.  It would seem I need a unique list every time through the loop.

Is there any way to limit the check mark to displaying only on the OptionMenu that the user has interacted with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in the ttk implementation of `OptionMenu`. It isn't assigning a unique variable for the radiobuttons in each OptionMenu.

You can fix this with a little bit of code. Basically, you have to loop over every item in the menu and set the `variable` attribute.

Here's an example:

```
def optionmenu_patch(om, var):
    menu = om['menu']
    last = menu.index("end")
    for i in range(0, last+1):
        menu.entryconfig(i, variable=var)
...
for each in range(10):
    sv = StringVar()
    om = OptionMenu(root, sv, choices[0], *choices)
    om.pack()
    optionmenu_patch(om, sv)
```

Bug tracker issue: http://bugs.python.org/issue25684

Comment: Thank you for dropping the bug report.  Your patch is working perfectly in the meantime.

Comment: Bryan, not sure if you noticed this or not, but the last person to comment on that bug (two days after you posted it) asked for a patch from you.

Comment: There is now a pull request for the issue, which I just reviewed.  I will try to make sure it is merged before any more releases.